# Modprobe error at boot

Tags: linux, lvm, boot, luks, modprobe

I'm using LMDE4 with LVM on LUKS and recently I've been getting these cryptic error messages at boot:

```
modprobe: module aes-i586 not found in modules.dep
    Volume group "lvmlmde" not found
    Cannot process volume group lvmlmde
    Volume group "lvmlmde" not found
    Cannot process volume group lvmlmde
Please unlock disk lvmlmde:
```

`lsblk` output:

```
NAME               MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                  8:0    0 238,5G  0 disk  
├─sda1               8:1    0   976M  0 part  /boot
└─sda2               8:2    0 237,5G  0 part  
  └─lvmlmde        254:0    0 237,5G  0 crypt 
    ├─lvmlmde-root 254:1    0 233,6G  0 lvm   /
    └─lvmlmde-swap 254:2    0     4G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
sr0                 11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

`dmesg` output:

```
[    2.855596] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    2.871879] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.871881] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    2.874372] input: PixArt USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:093A:2510.0001/input/input4
[    2.874471] hid-generic 0003:093A:2510.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [PixArt USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input0
[    2.924727] random: cryptsetup: uninitialized urandom read (4 bytes read)
[    3.418045] psmouse serio2: trackpoint: IBM TrackPoint firmware: 0x0e, buttons: 3/3
[    3.446521] usb 5-2: new full-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
[    3.623109] input: TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/input/input3
[    3.640559] usb 5-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0483, idProduct=2016, bcdDevice= 0.01
[    3.640562] usb 5-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    3.640564] usb 5-2: Product: Biometric Coprocessor
[    3.640565] usb 5-2: Manufacturer: STMicroelectronics
[    5.607628] NET: Registered protocol family 38
[    5.621228] cryptd: max_cpu_qlen set to 1000
[    5.776410] random: cryptsetup: uninitialized urandom read (2 bytes read)
[    5.805509] random: lvm: uninitialized urandom read (4 bytes read)
[    5.863363] random: lvm: uninitialized urandom read (4 bytes read)
[    6.098499] raid6: sse2x1   gen()  3154 MB/s
[    6.166494] raid6: sse2x1   xor()  3673 MB/s
[    6.234490] raid6: sse2x2   gen()  3733 MB/s
[    6.302489] raid6: sse2x2   xor()  4477 MB/s
[    6.370496] raid6: sse2x4   gen()  6627 MB/s
[    6.438491] raid6: sse2x4   xor()  4920 MB/s
[    6.438492] raid6: using algorithm sse2x4 gen() 6627 MB/s
[    6.438493] raid6: .... xor() 4920 MB/s, rmw enabled
[    6.438494] raid6: using ssse3x2 recovery algorithm
[    6.450339] xor: measuring software checksum speed
[    6.486485]    prefetch64-sse:  8278.000 MB/sec
[    6.526485]    generic_sse:  7359.000 MB/sec
[    6.526486] xor: using function: prefetch64-sse (8278.000 MB/sec)
[    6.610533] Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-generic
[    6.805887] PM: Image not found (code -22)
[    7.038907] EXT4-fs (dm-1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    7.384848] systemd[1]: Inserted module 'autofs4'
[    7.421604] systemd[1]: systemd 241 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[    7.438602] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[    7.443937] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <jenny>.
[    7.596112] urandom_read: 1 callbacks suppressed
[    7.596113] random: lvmconfig: uninitialized urandom read (4 bytes read)
[    7.669929] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    7.681009] systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/thinkfan.service:8: PIDFile= references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/thinkfan.pid → /run/thinkfan.pid; please update the unit file accordingly.
[    7.709742] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    7.709836] systemd[1]: Listening on initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[    7.710017] systemd[1]: Started Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch.
[    7.712150] systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dcryptsetup.slice.
[    7.712313] systemd[1]: Listening on fsck to fsckd communication Socket.
[    7.712349] systemd[1]: systemd-journald-dev-log.socket: Socket service systemd-journald.service not loaded, refusing.
[    7.712468] systemd[1]: Failed to listen on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[    7.730955] systemd[336]: ufw.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    7.734301] systemd[337]: kmod-static-nodes.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    7.737629] systemd[338]: systemd-modules-load.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    7.745118] systemd[339]: systemd-remount-fs.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    7.755713] systemd[343]: keyboard-setup.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    7.756324] systemd[344]: lvm2-monitor.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    7.756404] systemd[341]: blk-availability.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    7.774922] systemd[347]: systemd-udev-trigger.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    7.813159] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[    7.813240] systemd-modules-load[338]: Inserted module 'lp'
[    7.820409] EXT4-fs (dm-1): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[    7.836410] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[    7.836484] systemd-modules-load[338]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
[    7.841470] systemd[357]: systemd-random-seed.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    7.852010] systemd-modules-load[338]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
[    7.852539] systemd[356]: systemd-sysusers.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    7.859573] systemd[359]: systemd-sysctl.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    7.869308] systemd[360]: systemd-udev-trigger.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    7.923654] systemd[361]: systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    7.946678] systemd-tmpfiles[361]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:1] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher → /run/speech-dispatcher; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
[    7.946693] systemd-tmpfiles[361]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:2] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher/.cache → /run/speech-dispatcher/.cache; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
[    7.946707] systemd-tmpfiles[361]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:3] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher/.speech-dispatcher → /run/speech-dispatcher/.speech-dispatcher; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
[    7.946722] systemd-tmpfiles[361]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:4] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher/.cache/speech-dispatcher → /run/speech-dispatcher/.cache/speech-dispatcher; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
[    7.946738] systemd-tmpfiles[361]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:5] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher/log → /run/speech-dispatcher/log; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
[    7.963453] systemd[363]: systemd-udevd.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    8.214213] input: Lid Switch as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input5
[    8.214420] ACPI: Lid Switch [LID]
[    8.214513] input: Sleep Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input6
[    8.214528] ACPI: Sleep Button [SLPB]
[    8.214627] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input7
[    8.214640] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
[    8.228735] ACPI: Video Device [VID1] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    8.273369] acpi device:07: registered as cooling_device2
[    8.273469] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:06/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input8
[    8.273571] ACPI: AC Adapter [AC] (on-line)
[    8.313757] battery: ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT0] (battery present)
[    8.335545] tpm_tis 00:05: 1.2 TPM (device-id 0xFFFF, rev-id 255)
[    8.343376] tpm tpm0: [Hardware Error]: Adjusting reported timeouts: A 10000->10000us B 10000->10000us C 0->752000us D 0->752000us
[    8.382609] Non-volatile memory driver v1.3
[    8.392741] systemd-udevd[380]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v240'.
[    8.412527] intel_rng: FWH not detected
[    8.443791] systemd-udevd[380]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
[    8.471666] leds_ss4200: no LED devices found
[    8.471720] thinkpad_acpi: ThinkPad ACPI Extras v0.26
[    8.471721] thinkpad_acpi: http://ibm-acpi.sf.net/
[    8.471722] thinkpad_acpi: ThinkPad BIOS 7CETC6WW (2.16 ), EC 7CHT21WW-1.09
[    8.471723] thinkpad_acpi: Lenovo ThinkPad R60, model 9461DXG
[    8.471725] thinkpad_acpi: WARNING: Outdated ThinkPad BIOS/EC firmware
[    8.471725] thinkpad_acpi: WARNING: This firmware may be missing critical bug fixes and/or important features
[    8.471801] sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 5
[    8.471881] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[    8.485006] thinkpad_acpi: radio switch found; radios are disabled
[    8.485029] thinkpad_acpi: This ThinkPad has standard ACPI backlight brightness control, supported by the ACPI video driver
[    8.485030] thinkpad_acpi: Disabling thinkpad-acpi brightness events by default...
[    8.508267] thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: radio is blocked
[    8.531558] iTCO_vendor_support: vendor-support=0
[    8.536531] iTCO_wdt: Intel TCO WatchDog Timer Driver v1.11
[    8.536643] iTCO_wdt: Found a ICH7-M or ICH7-U TCO device (Version=2, TCOBASE=0x1060)
[    8.538853] iTCO_wdt: initialized. heartbeat=30 sec (nowayout=0)
[    8.554149] yenta_cardbus 0000:15:00.0: CardBus bridge found [17aa:202f]
[    8.554175] yenta_cardbus 0000:15:00.0: Using INTVAL to route CSC interrupts to PCI
[    8.554177] yenta_cardbus 0000:15:00.0: Routing CardBus interrupts to PCI
[    8.554184] yenta_cardbus 0000:15:00.0: TI: mfunc 0x01001b22, devctl 0x64
[    8.564506] thinkpad_acpi: Standard ACPI backlight interface available, not loading native one
[    8.564611] thinkpad_acpi: Console audio control enabled, mode: monitor (read only)
[    8.574886] thinkpad_acpi: battery 1 registered (start 0, stop 0)
[    8.574893] battery: new extension: ThinkPad Battery Extension
[    8.574950] input: ThinkPad Extra Buttons as /devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/input/input9
[    8.656068] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: probe_mask set to 0x1 for device 17aa:2010
[    8.707378] snd_hda_codec_analog hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for AD1981: line_outs=1 (0x5/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    8.707382] snd_hda_codec_analog hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    8.707384] snd_hda_codec_analog hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    8.707385] snd_hda_codec_analog hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    8.707387] snd_hda_codec_analog hdaudioC0D0:    dig-out=0xa/0x0
[    8.707389] snd_hda_codec_analog hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    8.707391] snd_hda_codec_analog hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x8
[    8.707393] snd_hda_codec_analog hdaudioC0D0:      CD=0x19
[    8.793419] systemd-udevd[383]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
[    8.795362] yenta_cardbus 0000:15:00.0: ISA IRQ mask 0x0cf8, PCI irq 16
[    8.795366] yenta_cardbus 0000:15:00.0: Socket status: 30000086
[    8.795373] yenta_cardbus 0000:15:00.0: pcmcia: parent PCI bridge window: [io  0x9000-0xcfff]
[    8.795375] yenta_cardbus 0000:15:00.0: pcmcia: parent PCI bridge window: [mem 0xe4300000-0xe7ffffff]
[    8.795378] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: cs: memory probe 0xe4300000-0xe7ffffff:
[    8.795381]  excluding 0xe4300000-0xe46cffff
[    8.795390] yenta_cardbus 0000:15:00.0: pcmcia: parent PCI bridge window: [mem 0xe0000000-0xe3ffffff 64bit pref]
[    8.795392] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: cs: memory probe 0xe0000000-0xe3ffffff:
[    8.795396]  excluding 0xe0000000-0xe3ffffff
[    8.830197] input: HDA Digital PCBeep as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input10
[    8.898636] systemd[535]: systemd-cryptsetup@lvmlmde.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    8.900699] systemd[534]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-da7fb045\x2d11e5\x2d45f6\x2d8a2d\x2d394d10e2ffaa.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    8.919387] systemd-cryptsetup[535]: Volume lvmlmde already active.
[    8.939867] systemd[538]: systemd-fsckd.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.035898] systemd[546]: boot.mount: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.051318] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    9.065593] intel_powerclamp: No package C-state available
[    9.097427] intel_powerclamp: No package C-state available
[    9.139815] systemd[570]: lvm2-pvscan@254:0.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.337821] systemd[605]: dev-mapper-lvmlmde\x2dswap.swap: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.351630] Adding 4124668k swap on /dev/mapper/lvmlmde-swap.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:4124668k SSFS
[    9.391555] systemd[611]: tmp.mount: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.403988] systemd[613]: systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.409619] systemd[614]: apparmor.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.411364] systemd[616]: console-setup.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.428075] systemd-tmpfiles[613]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:1] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher → /run/speech-dispatcher; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
[    9.428136] systemd-tmpfiles[613]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:2] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher/.cache → /run/speech-dispatcher/.cache; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
[    9.428194] systemd-tmpfiles[613]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:3] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher/.speech-dispatcher → /run/speech-dispatcher/.speech-dispatcher; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
[    9.428251] systemd-tmpfiles[613]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:4] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher/.cache/speech-dispatcher → /run/speech-dispatcher/.cache/speech-dispatcher; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
[    9.428312] systemd-tmpfiles[613]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:5] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher/log → /run/speech-dispatcher/log; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
[    9.483358] random: crng init done
[    9.508355] systemd[632]: systemd-update-utmp.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.510899] audit: type=1400 audit(1617986458.304:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-xpdfimport" pid=627 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.519694] audit: type=1400 audit(1617986458.312:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=628 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.519697] audit: type=1400 audit(1617986458.312:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session//chromium" pid=628 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.527472] audit: type=1400 audit(1617986458.320:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=634 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.527474] audit: type=1400 audit(1617986458.320:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=634 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.531209] audit: type=1400 audit(1617986458.324:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/man" pid=633 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.531214] audit: type=1400 audit(1617986458.324:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_filter" pid=633 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.531215] audit: type=1400 audit(1617986458.324:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_groff" pid=633 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.538469] audit: type=1400 audit(1617986458.328:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-senddoc" pid=635 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.543954] audit: type=1400 audit(1617986458.336:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="torbrowser_tor" pid=636 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.623815] systemd[659]: networking.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.647406] systemd[667]: alsa-state.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.649745] systemd[668]: mintsystem.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.654008] systemd[670]: upower.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.668284] systemd[664]: acpi-support.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.668450] systemd[671]: ksm.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.671811] systemd[674]: systemd-logind.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.673339] systemd[672]: thinkfan.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.673535] systemd[673]: mytaskkiller.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.677814] systemd[675]: irqbalance.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.706962] systemd[678]: dbus.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.707338] systemd[679]: NetworkManager.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.708147] systemd[681]: lm-sensors.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.715154] systemd[687]: udisks2.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.717439] systemd[683]: debian-system-adjustments.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.785237] systemd-udevd[391]: Process '/usr/sbin/tlp auto' failed with exit code 4.
[    9.802089] systemd-logind[674]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event6 (Power Button)
[    9.818158] iwl3945: Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 3945ABG/BG Network Connection driver for Linux, in-tree:s
[    9.818160] iwl3945: Copyright(c) 2003-2011 Intel Corporation
[    9.818161] iwl3945: hw_scan is disabled
[    9.818257] iwl3945 0000:03:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[    9.831951] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: cs: memory probe 0x0c0000-0x0fffff:
[    9.831960]  excluding 0xc0000-0xcffff 0xdc000-0xfffff
[    9.831994] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: cs: memory probe 0xa0000000-0xa0ffffff:
[    9.832006]  excluding 0xa0000000-0xa0ffffff
[    9.832031] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: cs: memory probe 0x60000000-0x60ffffff:
[    9.832043]  excluding 0x60000000-0x60ffffff
[    9.874853] iwl3945 0000:03:00.0: Tunable channels: 13 802.11bg, 23 802.11a channels
[    9.874858] iwl3945 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel Wireless WiFi Link 3945ABG
[    9.895423] systemd-logind[674]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event4 (Lid Switch)
[    9.895732] systemd-logind[674]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event5 (Sleep Button)
[    9.895995] systemd-logind[674]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event0 (AT Translated Set 2 keyboard)
[    9.896315] systemd-logind[674]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event8 (ThinkPad Extra Buttons)
[    9.914258] systemd-logind[674]: New seat seat0.
[   10.041402] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-3945-rs'
[   10.062334] systemd-udevd[383]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v240'.
[   10.073913] systemd-udevd[383]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
[   10.088059] iwl3945 0000:03:00.0 wls3: renamed from wlan0
[   10.131633] systemd[742]: lm-sensors.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[   10.264099] systemd[782]: clamav-freshclam.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[   10.264275] systemd[779]: systemd-user-sessions.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[   10.311618] systemd[788]: polkit.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[   10.339792] systemd[794]: lightdm.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[   10.374775] systemd[797]: lightdm.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[   10.534983] [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled.
[   10.548440] [drm] initializing kernel modesetting (RV515 0x1002:0x7145 0x17AA:0x2006 0x00).
[   10.551249] resource sanity check: requesting [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff], which spans more than PCI Bus 0000:00 [mem 0x000d0000-0x000d3fff window]
[   10.551258] caller pci_map_rom+0x6a/0x1b0 mapping multiple BARs
[   10.551354] ATOM BIOS: M64CSP/M62CSP/M54CSP/M52CSP
[   10.551385] [drm] Generation 2 PCI interface, using max accessible memory
[   10.551392] radeon 0000:01:00.0: VRAM: 128M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x0000000007FFFFFF (128M used)
[   10.551395] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GTT: 512M 0x0000000008000000 - 0x0000000027FFFFFF
[   10.551419] [drm] Detected VRAM RAM=128M, BAR=128M
[   10.551420] [drm] RAM width 128bits DDR
[   10.554668] [TTM] Zone  kernel: Available graphics memory: 1536476 kiB
[   10.554670] [TTM] Initializing pool allocator
[   10.554676] [TTM] Initializing DMA pool allocator
[   10.554713] [drm] radeon: 128M of VRAM memory ready
[   10.554715] [drm] radeon: 512M of GTT memory ready.
[   10.554740] [drm] GART: num cpu pages 131072, num gpu pages 131072
[   10.592359] [drm] radeon: power management initialized
[   10.608079] [drm] radeon: 1 quad pipes, 1 z pipes initialized.
[   10.661707] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): ens2: link is not ready
[   10.743546] systemd[833]: tlp.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[   10.863722] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): ens2: link is not ready
[   10.907159] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wls3: link is not ready
[   10.940335] [drm] PCIE GART of 512M enabled (table at 0x0000000000040000).
[   10.940370] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[   10.940375] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000008000000 and cpu addr 0x0000000070cf6855
[   10.940378] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[   10.940379] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[   10.940381] radeon 0000:01:00.0: radeon: MSI limited to 32-bit
[   10.940399] [drm] radeon: irq initialized.
[   10.940419] [drm] Loading R500 Microcode
[   10.987459] radeon 0000:01:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/R520_cp.bin
[   10.987854] [drm] radeon: ring at 0x0000000008001000
[   10.987898] [drm] ring test succeeded in 3 usecs
[   11.000629] systemd[881]: systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[   11.019256] [drm] ib test succeeded in 0 usecs
[   11.033946] [drm] Radeon Display Connectors
[   11.033948] [drm] Connector 0:
[   11.033949] [drm]   VGA-1
[   11.033951] [drm]   DDC: 0x7e40 0x7e40 0x7e44 0x7e44 0x7e48 0x7e48 0x7e4c 0x7e4c
[   11.033951] [drm]   Encoders:
[   11.033952] [drm]     CRT1: INTERNAL_KLDSCP_DAC1
[   11.033953] [drm] Connector 1:
[   11.033954] [drm]   LVDS-1
[   11.033956] [drm]   DDC: 0x7e60 0x7e60 0x7e64 0x7e64 0x7e68 0x7e68 0x7e6c 0x7e6c
[   11.033956] [drm]   Encoders:
[   11.033957] [drm]     LCD1: INTERNAL_LVTM1
[   11.033958] [drm] Connector 2:
[   11.033958] [drm]   SVIDEO-1
[   11.033959] [drm]   Encoders:
[   11.033960] [drm]     TV1: INTERNAL_KLDSCP_DAC2
[   11.033961] [drm] Connector 3:
[   11.033961] [drm]   DVI-I-1
[   11.033962] [drm]   HPD1
[   11.033963] [drm]   DDC: 0x7e50 0x7e50 0x7e54 0x7e54 0x7e58 0x7e58 0x7e5c 0x7e5c
[   11.033964] [drm]   Encoders:
[   11.033965] [drm]     DFP1: INTERNAL_KLDSCP_TMDS1
[   11.112019] systemd-udevd[402]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v240'.
[   11.443338] [drm] fb mappable at 0xD80C0000
[   11.443340] [drm] vram apper at 0xD8000000
[   11.443341] [drm] size 5914624
[   11.443342] [drm] fb depth is 24
[   11.443343] [drm]    pitch is 5632
[   11.443850] fbcon: radeondrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[   11.509339] thinkpad_ec: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   11.509408] thinkpad_ec: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   11.509958] thinkpad_ec: thinkpad_ec 0.43 loaded.
[   11.512389] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 175x65
[   11.513042] tp_smapi 0.43 loading...
[   11.514946] tp_smapi successfully loaded (smapi_port=0xb2).
[   11.517590] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fb0: radeondrmfb frame buffer device
[   11.534622] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.50.0 20080528 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
[   11.704378] systemd[792]: getty@tty1.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[   13.212024] systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of UID 119.
[   13.213859] systemd[1]: Starting User Runtime Directory /run/user/119...
[   13.214981] systemd[1191]: user-runtime-dir@119.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone know this error and what might be causing it?

Comment: Looks like syslogs, not blkid output...

Comment: Indeed, that was the `dmesg` output. Here is `blkid`: /dev/sda1: 

`UUID="da7fb045-11e5-45f6-8a2d-394d10e2ffaa" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="a8598212-01"`
    
`/dev/sda2: UUID="e2c15029-209d-48e9-b148-95dd8fb6aefc" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="a8598212-02"`
    
`/dev/mapper/lvmlmde: UUID="uIIRmW-MkUH-3HDu-VA3h-DBoa-ANqJ-ryOtPI" TYPE="LVM2_member"`
    
`/dev/mapper/lvmlmde-root: UUID="1986bf13-58d3-4b4e-b288-4e707fa9a074" TYPE="ext4"`
    
`/dev/mapper/lvmlmde-swap: UUID="ed8eaafc-6346-4037-a042-d943361f3c3c" TYPE="swap"`

Comment: Also, the `dmesg` output is cropped as I hit the max. text length limit... Please let me know if you need any other information ^^

Comment: The "VG Not Found" errors occur for me, nothing to worry there (it's a weird way the log works) and I think the modprobe error is nothing to worry about? (edit: `s/>/?/`)